# Outlook 2010 to SharePoint 2010 and vice-versa not sync hing items

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, outlook

I have a calendar list in SharePoint 2010 which is synchronized to Outlook 2010 it was working fine earlier. Now when I add anything in the calendar from SharePoint, it is not showing up in Outlook. Same way When I add items in Outlook they are not showing up in SharePoint.

Both the versions of SharePoint and Outlook are 2010. No custom columns have been added. Tried reconnecting to outlook by deleting the list connection from Outlook but of no use. Anybody has this kind of issues. Can someone suggest/ help me on this.

[image]

I found this error on my outlook any ideas on how to over come this. I have a real urgency on this.

Comment: It is working in my dev environment which has same set up as of beta and Prod . This is not working in my both beta and Prod sites, Can anyone suggest something on this. It became a big headache to me.

Answer (score 0):

After long research and trial and errors I have done at my environments the issue has been resolved. I had to change the zone of our internal URL for our web application from "Intranet" to "Custom" zone. And now everything working from SharePoint to Outlook and Outlook to SharePoint. Big sigh of relief now. Hope this helps lot of people who are stuck with it.